# Unity: Adjusting 2D physics for different mobile resolutions

Tags: unity, rigid-body-dynamics, rigidbody

I created a test project to see how different mobile resolutions affects Unity's 2D Physics.

They way I handled the resolutions was to contain all the objects (including non-UI objects) in a Canvas and use a Canvas Scaler component to adjust for multiple resolutions. Although this approach is probably not one of the ways the Canvas was not meant to be used, it works well when working with a single orientation.

Despite the quick solution to handle the multiple resolutions, there seems to be the issue of the physics acting differently depending on what aspect ratio is being used.

Images can be viewed here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mszoX.jpg

The green and blue blocks both have the Rigidbody2D and Box Collider 2D components. The floor (big white block) only has a Box Collider 2D component.

As you can see from the images above, the different aspect ratios cause the blocks to collide with the floor at different times. Also, when using rigidbody.addforce in the Y direction, the different aspect ratios cause the blocks to jump at different heights.

Obviously these issues could cause an unfair advantage in a game with support for several resolutions.

So how would I go about adjusting the physics so that the blocks fall and jump at the same rates relative to the different resolutions?

Also if there is a more practical way to adjust for multiple resolutions that doesn't involve a plugin and doesn't break physics, let me know!

Comment: The "images" link shows only a single image, which doesn't illustrate the different collision times you describe. In any case, trying to adjust physics is likely to be a massive headache with questionable reliability. You'll likely have better results changing your camera to suit the resolution, and keeping your gameplay at a known constant scale.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. If you're doing this just to make your game adapt to different resolutions, there are easier,simpler and better ways of doing that.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the feedback. As I said, this was just a test to see how the 2D physics would react to multiple resolutions when the objects are scaled. I figured the canvas scaler would cause some problems, as it was too easy to adjust to most resolutions.

Comment: @SanSolo Thanks you, but I wasn't aware there was a right or wrong way. The quick 'n' easy method I used was most likely impractical but my post implied this. Also I'm not doing this for a game of mine, I was following along an android tutorial that didn't involve Unity. I figured it would be good practice to see if I could replicate the program using Unity. I tried to use a simple solution, but I quickly realized that it really wasn't the simple solution.

Comment: @DMGregory I went ahead and altered the camera as you suggested and it works great now!

Comment: Excellent! Are you going to write up your solution as an answer so readers coming later can benefit from your experience?

Comment: @DMGregory After reading your suggestion, I looked for different ways to alter the camera and came upon this [link](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.ie/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html) and prefered the approach! It worked really well for the project I'm working on!

Comment: @Alkhzar that too would be worth writing up as an answer - just be sure to link & credit the original author in your summary.

Comment: @DMGregory omg... I can't believe I forgot again! Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the canvas scaler as a solution, I went the route of DMGregory's suggestion and ended up finding this [blog](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.ie/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html) by Adrian Lopez that worked perfectly for my needs.

It turns out that using the canvas scaler to adjust gameobjects with physics components can impact the way gameobjects respond to the physics engine when changing from one aspect ratio to another. This approach would require fine tuning of the physics components' members to create consistent physics across all aspect ratios. Clearly, this is counterproductive to my original idea of a simple aspect ratio adjuster. This revelation and DMGregory's suggestion helped me decide to use another approach.

For the new approach, I went about researching different ways to adjust the camera and came upon the blog I linked earlier in my answer. What this approach does is re-size the camera according to the current screen height and width to add a letterbox or pillarbox effect in order to keep consistency across multiple resolutions. A bonus is that this approach does not alter the physics when changing to different aspect ratios.